JSON giving error "Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" Python
Here's my json:
"{\"question\": \"What artist released the hit song 'Hello' in 2015?\", \"answers\": [\"Taylor Swift\", \"Katy Perry\", \"$Adele\", \"Lady Gaga\"], \"topic\": \"Music in the 2010's\"}, {\"question\": \"Who is the featured artist on the song 'Despacito' by Luis Fonsi?\", \"answers\": [\"Enrique Iglesias\", \"Maluma\", \"$Justin Bieber\", \"Pitbull\"], \"topic\": \"Music in the 2010's\"}"

Then I get the Json error:
Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
I am simply performing json.loads() on that json.
I tried removing trailing commas and making sure I am using double quotes on property names as suggested here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jsondecodeerror-expecting-property-name-enclosed-in-double-quotes-line-1-column-2-char-1/. I then couldn't get passed this error.
I also tried passing the string on https://jsonchecker.com/ and it says it is valid json. Why is json.loads() not working?

In absence of information on what you did to get the text that you're showing in that first block: that's not JSON.

Please give us a minimal code example. We don't know if you have this exact string or if this is the string literal for Python.

Are the characters in your post (quotation mark, brace, backslash, ...) the actual characters of the string (i.e. the actual variable, if printed) containing your JSON, or the literal characters in your Python source file that form a string literal?

I get a different error: Extra data: line 1 column 165 (char 164). The problem is everything after \"Music in the 2010's\"}. I think this is supposed to be an array of objects, but it's missing the surrounding [].

The json data is a list of two json objects, each containing 3 keys 'topic', 'question', 'answers'.
The objects should be enclosed in square brackets so python's json module can identify the two objects:
s = "[{\"question\": \"What artist released the hit song 'Hello' in 2015?\", \"answers\": [\"Taylor Swift\", \"Katy Perry\", \"$Adele\", \"Lady Gaga\"], \"topic\": \"Music in the 2010's\"}, {\"question\": \"Who is the featured artist on the song 'Despacito' by Luis Fonsi?\", \"answers\": [\"Enrique Iglesias\", \"Maluma\", \"$Justin Bieber\", \"Pitbull\"], \"topic\": \"Music in the 2010's\"}]"

pretty-printing may help a bit more to notice the two objects:
import json
from pprint import pprint

j = json.loads(s)
pprint(j)

[{'answers': ['Taylor Swift', 'Katy Perry', '$Adele', 'Lady Gaga'],
  'question': "What artist released the hit song 'Hello' in 2015?",
  'topic': "Music in the 2010's"},
 {'answers': ['Enrique Iglesias', 'Maluma', '$Justin Bieber', 'Pitbull'],
  'question': "Who is the featured artist on the song 'Despacito' by Luis "
              'Fonsi?',
  'topic': "Music in the 2010's"}]

